# Bluetooth doesn't exist in device manager?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, windows-7-x64

I'm facing weird problem with Windows 7 (dell inspiron 1564). I've installed the Bluetooth driver that is listed in Dell Drivers [here](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/ServiceTag/8Y2CYL1) with no hope. The Bluetooth device doesn't show in Device Manager neither in Programs list. I suspect the driver but not certain. Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with the driver. It has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test it but give it a try:

Go to `device manager` -> `view` -> `show hidden devices`.

Perhaps the bluetooth driver will be listed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue with bluetooth hardware on my machine. When checked I found, bluetooth hardware was not present on my PC and I tried several troubleshooting ,method available in windows. but no luck. further I found issue in the USB controller causing the bluetooth hardware problem.

To resolve the issue with the bluetooth hardware on your MS windows 10 PC, just uninstall the Intel (R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft) under Universal Bus Controller in device manager. It will reinstall the bluetooth hardware as well on the PC and you will be able to use the bluetooth device like wireless mouse, keyboard and wirephone earphone on your PC again. to do the same follow below steps

Go to Device Manager >> Universal Serial Bus Controller >> Right click on Intel (R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft) >> Click uninstall Device >> Then Right Click on your Machine hostname and select Scan for Hardware Changes as it will reinstall the default hardwares drivers and once don, bluetooth will be available on the PC again....